# Decrease number of ajax requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some checkboxes that act as search filters. These search filters trigger an ajax request and data is sent back from the server and displayed to the user. The problem is, there are several of these checkboxes and the user can select one after the other, selecting say, three in a row which equals 3 ajax requests. Ideally i would like only one ajax request be performed if the user has selected more than one search filter.

I'm trying to brainstorm and get some input on how i can wait for the user to finish checking the checkboxes before performing the ajax request. I've thought of alternatives such as adding a search button but it would be nice for the user to just select the options they want and be displayed the results.

I'm using jQuery, but mainly i'm just after ideas on how to implement this.

Comment: I suppose you could set a delay before the AJAX request is launched, and then count checkboxes, or else write code to cancel incomplete requests -- both of which are probably more trouble than they're worth. I think you'd be better off just optimizing the server code and returned data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the first checkbox is checked, set a `setTimeout` timer to a function to get search results. If another checkbox is set, reset the timer. If the user waits long enough for the setTimeout to fire, perform the search. That way you get the best of both worlds, fewer calls but automatic searching.

Comment: The only caveat here is that your `setTimeout` needs to be pretty short -- I'd say less than a second -- otherwise your user will think something's wrong.

Comment: That is true, default for jquery autocomplete is 300ms.

Comment: Ahh yes, this would work, seems a little messy code wise though. That's probably the best i'm going to get.

Comment: Its not that bad, pretty much what Uzi posted but using setTimeout instead of setInterval.

Answer (score 0):

A simple improvement is to set a timer, that sends the request only N ms after the last click (when N is lets say 500ms)

```
var intervalID;
$(".checkbox").bind('click', function() {
    if (intervalID) {
        window.clearInterval(intervalID);
    }

    intervalID = window.setInterval(submit, 500);
})

var submit = function() {
    window.clearInterval(intervalID);
    // submit the XHR call here
};
```

Comment: setInterval would cause the submission to happen every 500ms though.

Comment: Oh that's not a good idea, i don't really want to refresh the results every half second.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to clear the interval on submission. this is designed to do the exact opposite - to not send a request every checkbox click, but do so only if no other checkbox was clicked in the past N milliseconds, so this actually redices the potential number of calls vs setTimeout which you can not cancel.

Comment: i was not aware of that. good to know. still, concept is the same.